# How to set secret data to kubernetes secrets by yaml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using kubernetes to deploy a rails app to google container engine.

Follow the kubernetes secrets document: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/secrets.html

I created a web controller file:

```
# web-controller.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    name: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: gcr.io/my-project-id/myapp:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http-server
        env:
          secret:
          - secretName: mysecret
```

And created a secret file:

```
# secret.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  RAILS_ENV: production
```

When I run:

```
kubectl create -f web-controller.yml
```

It showed:

```
error: could not read an encoded object from web-controller.yml: unable to load "web-controller.yml": json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []v1.EnvVar
error: no objects passed to create
```

Maybe the yaml format is wrong in the `web-controller.yml` file. Then how to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `base64` encode the value and your key must be a valid DNS label, that is, replace `RAILS_ENV` with, for example, `rails-env`. See also this end-to-end example I put together [here](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2015/11/12/sharing-secret-data-in-kubernetes/) for more details and concrete steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read your post. It's very good. My problem is that I want to create a secret file to save my environment data. Such as `data: RAILS_ENV: cHJvZHVjdGlvbg==`. But when I run `kubectl create -f secret.yml`, it said: `* data[RAILS_ENV]: invalid value 'RAILS_ENV': must have at most 253 characters and match regex \.?[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*`. The naming is not right. Can't I set env data in secret file?

Comment: @scho I doubt you read the blog post carefully ;)  it says: "the key must be DNS name" and that means in your case: change the key to `rails-env` and it will work.

BTW, I'd really appreciate if you'd mark the answer as correct and up-vote it so that others that follow after you immediately know that they can rely upon it.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry, I didn't care that ;-(

Comment: No worries, happens to the best. As I said, please accept this as the correct answer …

Comment: I want to write down more information. Even I did that, and create web-controller again, the result was the same. The problem is the format in the web-controller.yml file is not right. Maybe now kubernetes secrets does not support that feature to set environment variables better.

Answer (score 3):

secret.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  RAILS_ENV: production
```

stringData is the easymode version of what you're after, one thing though.
you'll see the cleartext original yaml used to create the secret in the annotation (and if you used the above method that means you'll have a human readable secret in your annotation, if you use the below method you'll have the base64'd secret in your annotation), unless you follow up with the erase annotation command like so:

**kubectl apply -f secret.yml 

kubectl annotate secret mysecret kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration-** 

(the - at the end is what says to erase it) 
**kubectl get secret mysecret -n=api -o yaml** 

(to confirm)

Alternatively you'd do
**Bash# echo production | base64** 

cHJvZHVjdGlvbgo=

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  RAILS_ENV: cHJvZHVjdGlvbgo=
```

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support secrets exposed as env vars.

Comment: True back then, but no longer the case

Answer (score 0):

Lets Say we adding imagepull secrets in deployment now follow the steps,

`kubectl create secret docker-registry secret-name --docker-server=<registry-server-url> --docker-username=<Username> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<your-email>`

Now refer this in deployment yaml file,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-app
    image: <Image-name-private>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: secret-name
```

**OR**

Lets say you have some api key for access the application.

`kubectl create secret generic secret-name --from-literal api-key="<your_api-key"`

Now refer this in deployment like this.

```
        env:
          - name: API_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secret-name
                key: api-key
```